# What CSS style would be causing issues with a table plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Pricing Table by Supsystic with Peak theme. Unfortunately Yootheme's tech support are at best slow with responding to enquiries or at worse just simply ignore questions all together. My issue is that whenever I try to insert a table using the plugins shortcode there seems to be some conflict with the themes style. The 'Description Column' (left hand column) appears lower on the actual page than it looks on the preview page of the plugin. I've included images to assist you. You can also visit the issue by going to http://www.challenge-the-box.com/the-games

[image: Correct view on the plugin page]
[image: View on webpage]

Thanks!

Marc

Comment: This isn't a table, so it's best to remove the table tag you've added. And what's creating the inline heights on the divs? It looks like this is the root of your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Lee I've removed the table tag. Do you mean the div's in the plugin or the ones I've used on the page it appears alongside?

Comment: The divs itself, (for example I inspected the large space above 'choose your plan', and that has an inline height of about 60pixels. When I remove that styling, it seems to fit alot more (like it should in the first screenshot).

Comment: I have removed everything on the page other than the 'table', which appears to have removed the white space above the element. However, the second two columns are not inline with the left hand one.